# Why is javac telling me illegal start of expression?

Tags: javac

Here's my code, i do not know what I'm doing wrong seriously. I tried many different things like taking the public modifier away from get. but I still get the same thing. This program is supposed to print out the Nth number line in the pascal triangle do to that I am using recursion a little bit.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Triangle{

   private int lineNumber, count;
   private int[] num;

   public Triangle(){

      lineNumber = 1;
   }
   public Triangle(int n){

      set(n);
   }
   public void set(int n){

      if(n < 1){

         lineNumber = 1;
      }
      else{

         lineNumber = n;
      }
      public int get()//Triangle.java:26: error: ';' expected //
      {
         return lineNumber;
      }
      private void pascal(int[] row){ //Triangle.java:30: error: illegal start of expression

         if(count >= lineNumber){

            return;
         }
         num = new int[row.length + 1];
         num[0] = 1;
         for(int i = 1; i < row.length; i++){

            num[i] = row[i - 1] + row[i];
         }
         num[row.length] = 1;
         count ++;
         pascal(num);
         return;
      }
      public int[] output(){

         count = 1;
         num = new int[count];
         num[0] = 1;

         pascal(num);
         return num;
      }
      public static void main(String[] args){

         int i,userNum;

         Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.println("Enter a number to get the nth line of"+
                            " Pascal's Triangle." );
         userNum = input.nextInt();

         PascalTriangle triangle = new Triangle(userNum);
         int[] result = triangle.output();

         System.out.println("\n Line " + triangle.get() + " of "
                             + "Pascal's Triangle is ");
         for(i = 0; i < result.length; i++){

            System.out.println(result[i] + " ");
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: What's the exact error?

Comment: you are missing `}` for the `set(int n)` method.

Comment: Could you also post the error?

Answer (score 0):

You need one more closing bracket after the else statement in the set() method.Try to add the closing } before

```
else{

     lineNumber = n;
    }
  }
  public int get()//Triangle.java:26: error: ';' expected //
```